# Android NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance for es_US returns incorrect values

Tags: android, locale, currency, number-formatting

```
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
```

Locale is es_US

numberFormat is

```
 java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols[currency=USD,currencySymbol=$,decimalSeparator=,,digit=#,exponentSeparator=E,groupingSeparator=.,infinity=∞,intlCurrencySymbol=USD,minusSign=-,monetarySeparator=,,NaN=NaN,patternSeparator=;,perMill=‰,percent=%,zeroDigit=0]
```

The decimalSeparator and groupingSeparator are wrong, they should be . and , respectively. Is this a bug in Android?

EDIT:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) numberFormat).getDecimalFormatSymbols();

    if ("US".equalsIgnoreCase(locale.getCountry())
            && "es".equalsIgnoreCase(locale.getLanguage())) {
        decimalFormatSymbols.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator('.');
        decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    }

    ((DecimalFormat) numberFormat).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
```

This is one way to "fix" it, but it really seems like there should be a more locale friendly way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my question; yes, this is a known bug in Android:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38844

Supposedly fixed post 4.2, but here we are at 4.2.2